# Graphics to Sprite creates pixelated edges

Tags: phaser-framework

I have the latest sprite and have the following code:

```
let graphics = this.add.graphics();  

graphics.fillStyle(0xFF0000);
graphics.fillCircle(radius, radius, radius * 0.95);
graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
graphics.fillCircle(radius, radius, radius * 0.1);
graphics.generateTexture("BALL", radius * 2, radius * 2)

let ball = this.physics.add.sprite(this.platformWidth / 2, -100, "BALL");
```

The ball unfortunately has pixelated edges. In fact, there is almost a gray circle around the ball and that area specifically gets pixelated. This happens especially when I restart my scene as I move from one level to the next in my game.

I’d be grateful if you have any pointer on the issue?

Thanks,

Doug